# Gensim 3.8.0 to Gensim 4.0.0

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I have trained a Word2Vec model using Gensim 3.8.0. Later I tried to use the pretrained model using Gensim 4.0.o on GCP. I used the following code:

```
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(wv_path, binary= False)
words = model.wv.vocab.keys()
self.word2vec = {word:model.wv[word]%EMBEDDING_DIM for word in words}
```

I was getting error that "model.mv" has been removed from Gensim 4.0.0.
Then I used the following code:

```
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(wv_path, binary= False)
words = model.vocab.keys()
word2vec = {word:model[word]%EMBEDDING_DIM for word in words}
```

And getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0.
Use KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods .get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val) instead.
See https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4
```

Can anyone please suggest that how can I use the pretrained model & return a dictionary in Gensim 4.0.0?

Answer (score 31):

The changes caused by the migration from Gensim 3.x to 4 are all present in the github link:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4

For the above problem, the solution that worked for me:

```
    words = list(model.wv.index_to_key)
```

Answer (score 9):

The migration notes explain major changes & how to adapt your code:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4

Per the guidance there, to just get a list of the words, since your `model` variable is already an instance of `KeyedVectors`, you can use:

```
model.index_to_key
```

Your code doesn't show a need for a dict, but there is a slightly-different word-to-index-position dict in `model.key_to_index`. However, you can just use `model[key]` like before to get individual vectors.

(Separately: I can't imagine your `%EMBEDDING_DIM` is doing anything useful. Why would you want to perform an elementwise `%` modulus operation, using the integer count of dimensions, against individual dimensions that are often small floating-point numbers? It'll often be harmless, as the `EMBEDDING_DIM` will usually be far larger than the individual values, but it doesn't serve any good purpose.)

Answer (score 3):

On gensim 4.0.0 you will need to use the `key_to_index` method from the `KeyedVector` of your model, that will return you a `dict_keys` object with all the words -keys- on the model so you can still iterate through all your vocabulary :).

Your code should be now like this:

```
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(wv_path, binary= False)
words = list(model.wv.key_to_index.keys())
self.word2vec = {word:model.wv[word]%EMBEDDING_DIM for word in words}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
word_vocab= model.wv.vocab
```

I tried this but due to updating of gensim it's provide error like this:-

> The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0. Use
> KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods
> .get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val) instead.

Thus, I tried kew_to_index.keys() with list

```py
word_vocab= list(model.wv.key_to_index.keys())
```

and it's work well