# Word2VecKeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'index_to_key'

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-augmentation

I am trying to implement word2vec within nlpaug library and the following code :

```
aug = naw.WordEmbsAug(
    model_type='word2vec', model_path='GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin',
    action="insert")
```

gives me error of  :

```
Word2VecKeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'index_to_key'
```

How can i fix such an issue ?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: better show minimal working code which makes this problem. maybe problem in in different line - I don't see code wiht `index_to_key` in this code. You didn't show FULL error message so we don't know where exactly is `index_to_key` in code. And put it all in question, not in comments.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably related to the version of gensim you use. You can print the version with:

```
import gensim
print(gensim.__version__)
```

- https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4
- [Gensim 3.8.0 to Gensim 4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868221/gensim-3-8-0-to-gensim-4-0-0)

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this with gensim version 3.6, an upgrade to version 4.2 solved the problem.